# Apache Nutch at Amazon Web Services or Local

Tags: amazon-web-services, nutch

I want to learn Apache Nutch and I have an account at Amazon Web Services (AWS). I have three machines at AWS and one of them is micro sized, other one is small and the other one is medium. I want to start with small sized and I will install Nutch, Hadoop and Hbase on it. I have Centos 6 at my machines.

There is a question here but not I ask: [Nutch 2.1 (HBase, SOLR) with Amazon Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139296/nutch-2-1-hbase-solr-with-amazon-web-services)

I want to learn that which approach is better. I want to install them on small size machine. After that I want to add micro sized. On the other hand I don't have any experience about Nutch maybe I should work on local or is there a possibility using my machine and AWS both (does it charge more i.e. copying data from AWS may be charged.)

When I want to implement a wrapper into my Nutch, should I install it on my local(to have source codes) and run it on AWS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your facing a steep learning curve.

For one, you admit that you're just learning Nutch, so I would recommend you install CentOS on a physical box at home and play around there.

On the other hand, you are pondering the use of a micro AWS instance, which will not be useful in running a CPU/memory intensive application like Nutch. **Read about [AWS micro instances here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html).**

My suggestion is to stick to a single physical box solution at home and work on scripting your solution before moving on to an AWS instance.